# Error : Google Plus fallback bundle could not be found

Tags: ios, xcode, google-plus

I am integrating google plus with my ios project.....

i include all steps for integration from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

The sign page perfectly appar but while i click on share button which contain code

```
 - (IBAction)TestShareOnG:(id)sender {
      id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
      [shareBuilder open];
    }
```

the appliction crash and error occur..

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Google Plus fallback bundle could not be found. Please include it in the project.'**

Comment: The reason for this error is i added the GooglePlus.bundle in TARGETS.                                                             I solve this problem error just drag and drop the GooglePlus.bundle in your project....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having same problem

Make sure following

**1> add GoogleOpenSource.framework and GooglePlus.framework**

**2> add GooglePlus.bundle also**

I was missing 2nd...

Comment: I had both the steps done, I added the all 3 in build Phases-> Link binaries.....,
**Extra step** I just dragged and added the **GooglePlus.bundle** to the project